# Crosstab Queries Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to merge two cross-tab queries using Union or Join query.

Here is the list for my first crosstab rows: startTime, endTime

the columns: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday.

value: courseName

second crosstab query

rows: startTime, endTime

Columns: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday.

value: professorName

Now I want to merge these two values (courseName and professorName) in the same cell.

I am doing the union of the two queries but it is giving me courseName and professorName one on top of the other in two different cells. I want to be able to have them group in one unique cell.

the join put them in different cells horizontally

Is there any way I can put the courseName and the professorName in one cell?

Comment: How do you imagine the two values to be presented in one cell?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?But I will try to answer your question this way: I want the courseName on top and the professorName on the bottom in the cell.

Comment: or do you mean to say that it's not possible to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: I want to concatenate the two values in a cell like you would do with a string

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as text table(s). Build a query that concatenates course and professor then CROSSTAB that.

Comment: @June7 I am trying to proceed with your suggestions, but the problem is CourseName and professorName are from different table. How do we concatenate two fields from different table?

Comment: I searched everywhere on how to concatenate two fields from different table, but I didn't find any working solution.

Comment: Here are the two tables:  Staff Table:   PK staffID, firstName, lastName, dOB, address, phoneNum, title

Comment: course Table: PK courseID, FK staffID, courseName

Comment: As you can see there is no preofessorName. I just concatenate staff firstName and lastName to form professorName

Comment: Not showing date field. Edit question to show table info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build query that joins tables and concatenates fields.

```
SELECT Courses.*, Staff.*, courseName & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & firstName & " " & lastName AS Data 
FROM Staff INNER JOIN Courses ON Courses.[FK staffID] = Staff.[PK staffID];
```

Use that query as source for CROSSTAB.

Comment: Thank you so much @June7. I got it working. God Bless You!!!!